# How to change color theme for all widgets in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to change the color palette of a tkinter application, I don't know how to update all widgets with the new colors configuration.

I wrote this minimal reproducible example of what I'd need:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

COLOR_1 = 'white'
COLOR_2 = 'black'

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

        global COLOR_1, COLOR_2

        self.geometry('200x200+50+50')
        self.title('Theme Changer')

        menubar = Menu(self)
        thememenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
        thememenu.add_command(label='Theme 1', command=lambda: self.change_theme(1))
        thememenu.add_command(label='Theme 2', command=lambda: self.change_theme(2))
        thememenu.add_command(label='Theme 3', command=lambda: self.change_theme(3))
        menubar.add_cascade(label='Themes', menu=thememenu)

        self.configure(menu=menubar, background=COLOR_1)

        Label(self, text='SOME TEXT', background=COLOR_1, foreground=COLOR_2).pack()

    def change_theme(self, key):
        global COLOR_1, COLOR_2

        if key == 1:
            COLOR_1 = 'black'
            COLOR_2 = 'yellow'

        elif key == 2:
            COLOR_1 = 'yellow'
            COLOR_2 = 'blue'

        else:
            COLOR_1 = 'white'
            COLOR_2 = 'black'
        
        self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = App()
    myapp.mainloop()
```

Evidently the function  `update()` is not useful for this purpose.

How can I do what I need?

Comment: Note @Bryan Oakley's answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't able to find a similar question, so isn't there a method that can do this without save any widget in a data structure?

Comment: You can use `widget.winfo_children()` to retrieve the child widgets without the need to create another holder.

Comment: No there is not. You might be able to avoid creating your own data structure by using `self.winfo_children()` to get a list of all of `self`'s child widgets — and then configure each of them accordingly.

Comment: @Marino `option_add` is a basic widget method and is intended to do what you want to do, but you can easy run into exceptions here. So the best way is how Bryan stated in the linked Question.

Comment: @Marino as a exampel of the way that Henry mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102452/13629335